# Debug a managed dump file using visual studio 2010

Tags: .net, dump

I took a dump file of a managed process using both task manager and process explorer.
whatever I use I get when opening the file with visual studio 2010 as a description of dump summary:

```
Process architecture: x64
Error information: You cannot debug a 64 bit dump of a 32 bit process, you must collect a 32 bit dump of a 32 bit process
```

I can confirm that the .net process I took a dump of is a 32 bit one (on my 64 bit machine). How can I configure the dump process to take an appropriate dump so I can analyze it in VS (or any other place like windbg) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the fact that on a 64 bit computer task manager and process explorer takes a 64 bit dump of a 32 bit process. I don't know how that can happen without any warnings/errors when taking the dump.

If I take the dump using a 32 bit version of windbg than the dump is taken corectly.